# AWS ECS service call result in upstream connect error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a service, and i want to call this service in aws throu CloudFront -> ALB -> ECS Service.
This service fully functional in local environment, but only partly funcional in aws (there are endpoints that works fine).

Unfortunately I have one endpoint that is not working in aws, I see that it gets called in the service it also returns 200, but from cloudfront, i get 502 with response body: "upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: protocol error"

My configuration is:

- The ECSService is configured for service connect.
- ALB as origin for CloudFront is only HTTP.

The errored endpoint is a POST with request body and two request param, and it returns json object.

### UPDATE

I managed to get it working by removing the server side of the service connect (I dont'n need that for this particular service).

If anybody can help me what could be the problem here (with server side service connect) i would still appreciate it.